# Why do I get the error: ".isValid()" is not a function?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to validate a model called `Book` based on the availability of an attribute, with the help of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niYCJOMZPJw&list=PLTjRvDozrdlwn9IsHWEs9IQv3HQob4bH3&index=3). I am trying to follow the instructions on how to validate a Backbone.js model, but when I go to validate an instance of it called `myBook` using the `.isValid()` method, it returns the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: myBook.isValid() is not a function
```

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript">
  var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    validate: function(attrs) {
      if (!attrs.title) {
        return "What's a book without a title?!";
      }
    }
  });

  var myBook = new Book();
  /* validation is run in browser */
</script>
```

This was similar to what was in the video linked above. When I go into the console and run the `.isValid()` method, it returns said error.

Comment: The error message is clear. myBook is not what you aspect but to understand why we need code.

Comment: read the error message, the function is not defined.. where is that being declared. paste some code dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been hard to help you if you hadn't provided the code sample which has the answer in it.

**[Backbone 0.3.3](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/3505bde58ec82f15e920298813d37476242793bb/backbone.js) doesn't have `isValid` yet.**

It was [added in Backbone 0.9.1](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/655bd05bc3fbe394277ffa38b51a5ca17b48d3b6/backbone.js#L450) but got removed in [0.9.9](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/18b445e8a0eaf438dd244121e24a2a6041c62052/backbone.js).

It was improved and [added back in 1.0](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/699fe3271262043bb137bae97bd0003d6d193f27/backbone.js#L555).

After upgrading Backbone and related to the comment about `h.has is not a function`, you also need to upgrade underscore.js as `_.has` was added in 1.3.1.

You should really **use the latest stable release of the libs** for your project as you'll avoid incompatibilities like that.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I never look at the specs for a library's version. I'm going to have to use a new version of Backbone.

Comment: Okay, I ran this same code with Backbone 1.0, now I'm getting a weird error from the version itself, saying that `h.has is not a function.` What is going on?

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue there was a lot of changes between 0.3.3 and 1.0. Since you're going through the upgrade process, I would advise you to use the latest version (1.3.3) right away.

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue Also, that question was answered, if you're facing a new problem, first try to solve it, then if everything else fails, ask a new question. By the way, you also need to update underscore as the `_.has` function was added in 1.3.1

Comment: Thanks. I apologize for not addressing this problem on my own. I need to look at the specs for a library's version next time.